# Installed phpList with joomla and get 404 error

Tags: joomla, phplist

I recently installed phpList in a folder of my current joomla install (on share server in bluehost). I had to manually install it, and I can access the admin page.

Joomla is installed at the root folder (`html_public`) and phpList in a folder within it (`html_public/phpList`).

As said, I can successfully access the admin page of phpList (`www.my-site.com/phpList/lists/admin`) and configure it.

**The problem is**: every time I click on "save" to save an updated configuration, then it re-directs me to a `404 - not found` throw by joomla (as it redirects to `http://www.my-site.com/lists/admin/?page=configure#item_confirmationmessage`). My updated configuration is correctly saved, and I can easily go back to it pressing the "back" button in the browser. I notice that phpList is not redirecting to the correct folder `html_public/phpList/lists` but to an incorrect one: `html_public/lists`.

I think there has to be some tweak to do in joomla and/or phpList to correctly define the folder it should direct the confirmation message.

I'm fully aware of the alternative of installing phpList to a subdomain's root folder, but at this point I'd prefer (if possible) to fix what I actually have.

Comment: The problem is that it is looking for a Joomla page with that name. You might want to try making a joomla menu link of type external link that has phpList as an alias and that goes to that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended doing, if it's of help to people looking for solutions.

It seems `phpList` is somewhat picky about the folder it's installed to.

In order to avoid conflicts with the already existing Joomla install, I had to create a subdomain and then make a clean re-install of it to a folder called `lists` within that subdomain. Any other solution (for example installing it to `lists` within `html_public` of my main domain) didn't work well, producing errors similar to the one described in the question. So, step by step:

1. Create a subdomain to your site (mine was "lists.mysite.com")
2. Install phpList into a folder called `lists` within that subdomain's `html_public` folder. Make sure you follow the guide in phpList documentation
3. Configure and go.